# SQL - The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am getting this error any time when i run below query. Even i use option (maxrecursion 0), it doesn't fail but taking long and still couldn't see it finished. So i have to fix my recursive code or need to same without recursive. Basically there are 2 tables one is for employees and other is for their contracts. Each employee under same parent can have one contract(Parent can have or child can have. It doesn't matter but they can have only one.It means there is one row(one contract) for same family). I need to get all contracts numbers and put same columns for all parents and childs.

`----------------------------
¦ Contract                  ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ ID_CONTRACT  ¦ ID_EMPLOYEE¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 1            ¦ 1          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 2            ¦ 4          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 3            ¦ 6          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 4            ¦ 7          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 5            ¦ 12         ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 6            ¦ 11         ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦`

`----------------------------
¦ Employee                  ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ ID_EMPLOYEE  ¦ ID_MANAGER ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 1            ¦ NULL       ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 2            ¦ 1          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 3            ¦ 1          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 4            ¦ NULL       ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 5            ¦ NULL       ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 6            ¦ NULL       ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 7            ¦ 5          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 8            ¦ NULL       ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 9            ¦ 5          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 10           ¦ 5          ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 11           ¦ NULL       ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦
¦ 12           ¦ NULL       ¦
¦--------------¦------------¦`

And my code is :

```
        drop table #cnt
        select DISTINCT 
            cnt.ID_CONTRACT,
            emp.ID_EMPLOYEE,
            emp.ID_MANAGER 
        into #cnt
        from 
            contract cnt (NOLOCK)
        inner join 
            employee emp (NOLOCK) ON cnt.ID_EMPLOYEE = emp.ID_EMPLOYEE

        ;WITH contactRec AS 
            (SELECT 
                cnt.ID_CONTRACT,cnt.ID_EMPLOYEE, cnt.ID_MANAGER
             FROM  
                #cnt cnt
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 
                cnt.ID_CONTRACT,emp.ID_EMPLOYEE, emp.ID_MANAGER
             FROM  
                contactRec cnt
            Inner join employee emp  on emp.ID_MANAGER = cnt.ID_EMPLOYEE
          )
            select  
              [ID_CONTRACT]
              ID_EMPLOYEE,
              ID_MANAGER
            from contactRec
```

Comment: IS `cntrementRec` a typo or is this some other table?

Comment: @JNevill , thanks for warning. It is typo. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a WHERE clause to the recursive element of your CTE to force the recursion to stop. You may also want to add a "Path" field so you can identify recursive cycling which can cause infinite recursion issues:

```
WITH contactRec AS 
        (SELECT 
            cnt.ID_CONTRACT,cnt.ID_EMPLOYEE, cnt.ID_MANAGER,
            1 a depth, CAST(cnt.ID_Employee + '>' cnt.ID_Manager AS VARCHAR(5000)) as path
         FROM  
            #cnt cnt
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 
            cnt.ID_CONTRACT,emp.ID_EMPLOYEE, emp.ID_MANAGER,
            depth + 1 as depth, path + '>' + emp.ID_Manager as path
         FROM  
            contactRec cnt
         Inner join employee emp  on emp.ID_MANAGER = cnt.ID_EMPLOYEE
         WHERE depth <= 20 /*end recursion at 20 cycles*/
      )
        select  
          [ID_CONTRACT]
          ID_EMPLOYEE,
          ID_MANAGER,
          depth,
          path
        from contactRec;
```

Now it will die at 20 cycles and you will have a depth and path indicator to help give clues as to why you are in an infinite loop.

Comment: actually i don't have many parent-child levels. I have maximum 3 hierarcy levels. But why i have to die it at a certain cycle? There is any other way to solve this or always have to put where clause for stop it. BTW code worked fine and i tested for a few rows but i need to test for more tomorrow and will accept it as answer if couldn't find any bug. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The recursion would stop on it's own, but chances are you have something like: employeeA reports to employeeB who reports to employeeC who reports to employeeA... and it cycles endlessly. The code I've posted will help you identify which leg of your hierarchy is causing this infinite cycling. I can't outright solve the problem because the problem is most likely in your data. This code above gives you the tools to find it so you can fix the data or add code to prevent it.

Comment: I found that I also had to use CAST(... AS VARCHAR(5000)) AS Path in the recursive part of the CTE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to generate a maxrecursion error with the schema and data that you've provided. However, I do notice one thing that might be causing your issue with your recursion. The general form of a recursive cte is:

```
with cte as (

   «base case»

   UNION ALL

   «recursive query»
)
select *
from cte
```

(Which, by the way, you've got; I just want to reference the above in my observation). In your base case, you're selecting all employees. What is typically done is to select either the top- or bottom-level employees and then when you recurse you either go down the hierarchy or up (respectively). In your specific situation, it makes sense (to me anyways) to go from top to bottom because the top-level employees are easy to identify. Specifically, your base case changes from:

```
SELECT   cnt.ID_CONTRACT ,
        cnt.ID_EMPLOYEE ,
        cnt.ID_MANAGER
FROM     #cnt cnt
```

to

```
SELECT  cnt.ID_CONTRACT ,
        cnt.ID_EMPLOYEE ,
        cnt.ID_MANAGER
FROM    #cnt cnt
WHERE   ID_MANAGER IS NULL
```

But even that doesn't explain why you're hitting a recursion limit. Are you sure that your data is acyclic (that is, you don't have something like 1 → 2 → 1)?

Comment: That is good point but in my logic it won't work because, can make contract with any level of employee and only 1 contract for all family. If i use WHERE ID_MANAGER IS NULL , i may not found contract which not made with Manager. But I may use two recursive one is for going up level and one is for down.

Comment: Perhaps. What *semantic* query are you trying to answer? Right now, you are asking about a code problem, but the code as written might not answer the question you intend it to...

Comment: @JNevill asnwer work for me for now. But still couldn't confirm for all data.